# Performing a list operation in Python

Tags: python, list

I am removing `J1` from `J`. Corresponding to the removed indices, I want to alter `Ci[1]` and append to `Ci` as shown below but I am getting an error. I also present the expected output.

```
J=[2, 6, 9, 10]
J1=[6,10]
l=[]
l.append(J)
l.append([x for x in J if x not in J1])

Ci = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 30, 50, 80]]
A=Ci[1]([x for x in J if x not in J1])
print(A)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A=Ci[1]([x for x in J if x not in J1])

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The expected output is

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 30, 50, 80]],[[10, 50]]]
```

Comment: What is `A=Ci[1]([x for x in J if x not in J1])` supposed to mean? It's not correct python and I can't tell what you expected from that line

Comment: I want to use the same indices for ```J``` to remove specific elements from ```Ci[1]```.

Comment: Are you sure you want `[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 30, 50, 80]],[[10, 50]]]` and not just `[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 30, 50, 80], [10, 50]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect the indices first,

```py
lidx = [i for i in range(len(J)) if J[i] not in J1]
A = [Ci, [Ci[1][i] for i in lidx]]
```

Comment: ```[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 30, 50, 80]], [10, 50]]``` is your output. There are missing brackets in ```[10,50]```. It should be ```[[10, 50]]```.

Comment: Then `A = [Ci, [[Ci[1][i] for i in lidx]]]`, but in second element `[[Ci[1][i] for i in lidx]]` the outer brackets seems not neccesary. Why you need it?

Comment: @rustyhu So the dimensions are consistent. If you do just `[Ci, [Ci[1][i] for i in lidx]]`, then the elements in the first part have a depth of 3, but the elements in the second part of a depth of only 2. And if python was stronly typed you wouldn't be able to write a consistent type for `A`, is it a List(List(List(int))) or a List(List(int))?

Comment: @rustyhu When you write `Ci[1][i]` you're dereferencing `Ci` twice: once with `[1]`, once with `[i]`. So, to keep types consistent, it makes sense to rereference it twice, with `[[ ... ]]` and not just `[ ... ]`.

Comment: (Of course this is all just guessing on my part - without more context on this question I have no idea what `Ci` and `A` are used for anyway)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate on two lists simultaneously:

```py
A = [Ci, [[x for x,y in zip(Ci[1],J) if y not in J1]]]
print(A)
# [[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 30, 50, 80]], [[10, 50]]]
```

Comment: Your output is very close to mine but this is what I am looking for: ```[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 30, 50, 80]],[[10, 50]]]```.

Comment: @isaacmodi123 And now?

Comment: ```[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 30, 50, 80]], [10, 50]]``` is your output. There are missing brackets in ```[10,50]```.

Comment: @isaacmodi123 Fair point. I edited.